# What is the administrative effort to run a self hosted CI and version control system?

Tags: version-control, continuous-integration, saas

our small team of 2 people recently got upgraded to 5, which means we should introduce a bit more infrastructure around our project in order to work efficiently together. Its a university research project.

**How much administrative effort is it to run**

- Gitlab
- Jenkins
- A Release Server

**on a rented machine, in comparison to a SaaS solution e.g github with Travis ?**

Unfortunately nobody in our (quite academic) team has practical experience with that. I know the setup can be done fast, but how time consuming is it to keep the stuff running. Are there other concerns we might be missing?

Of course we would like to mainly work on the project itself, but since the toolstack keeps growing by time we are not sure if a SaaS solution is what we need.

Answer (score 0):

With these inputs be ready to spend from one to several weeks of one from the five.
Instead you might want to check which leading hosting companies provide free services for open source or educational projects.